# Angular lazy loading with parameters

Tags: angular

I am trying to get my head around lazy loading by following this article:

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-module-loading-eager-lazy-and-preloading

But it doesn't appear to work for me.
I have this route set up (before I started messing with the lazy loading) and it looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { StepsComponent } from './steps.component';

const stepRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'steps', redirectTo: 'steps/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'steps/:path', component: StepsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(stepRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class StepsRoutingModule { }
```

so I wanted to get that to lazy load. So at first I just removed my **StepsModule** from **AppModule** and updated the **AppRouting** module to this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

  // Lazy load
  //{ path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule '},
  { path: 'steps', loadChildren: 'app/steps/steps.module#StepsModule '}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And I changed my **StepsRouting** module to this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { StepsComponent } from './steps.component';

const stepRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'steps/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'steps/:path', component: StepsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(stepRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class StepsRoutingModule { }
```

But it doesn't work.
I can see that **StepsModule** is not loaded when I serve the application, but if I try to navigate to the **steps** view, I get no errors, the Url changes, but it doesn't load the **StepsModule**.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: No errors, if I comment out the catch all, I get this: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Angular's lazy loading is not as straightforward as it should. I found out that the lazy loaded module MUST have routes itself, even if it is to load one single component in it.

Comment: Have you added `router-outlet` in your `AppComponent` ?

Comment: yeah, as I said it was working fine without trying to lazy load

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now would make the route `/steps/steps/:path`. Remove `steps/` from `stepRoutes`:

```
{ path: ':path', component: StepsComponent }
```

Comment: That doesn't work :( I still get the error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function`

Comment: That error is usually an issue with where you are importing shared services and such. I've been able to get rid of these errors by moving things in/out of my app module and shared module. I'd have to see your whole codebase to help you more